# string index out of range Python, Django

Tags: python, django

i'm using Django to develop a web application. When i try and run it on my web form i am receiving 'string index out of range' error. However, when i hardcode a dictionary in to a python test file it works fine with the same values.

Here is my Django View:

```
def submitworkout(request):
    #workoutinfo = workout(request.GET)
    return render_to_response('home.html',{'infoprompt': workout(request.GET)},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Here is the object:

```
class workout():


    def __init__(self,addworkout):
        self.workout = collections.OrderedDict();
        getallreps = 0
        for i in range(len(addworkout['exercisename'])): 
            numsetcounter = 0; 
            self.workout[string.capwords(addworkout['exercisename'][i])] = [] 
            while numsetcounter < int(addworkout['numsets'][i]):   
                # print self.workout[addworkout['exercisename'][i]]
                self.workout[string.capwords(addworkout['exercisename'][i])].append([addworkout['weightinputboxes'][getallreps],addworkout['repinputboxes'][getallreps]]) 
                #[
                getallreps +=1
                numsetcounter +=1  

    def getexercise(self,name): 
        try: 
            return self.workout[string.capwords(name)];
        except:
            return 'This exercise does not exist!'
```

Now this is the dictionary i'm trying to run through the class:

```
addworkout =    
 {u'repinputboxes': [u'5', u'3'], u'weightinputboxes': [u'195', u'170'], u'numsets': [u'1', u'1'], u'exercisename': [u'Squat', u'Power Clean']}
```

and here are the local vars that Django is displaying on the error:

```
i=1 

numsetcounter =0

getallreps = 1
```

Hopefull you guys help me resolve my problem. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/submitworkout/?exercisename=Squat&numsets=1&weightinputboxes=195&repinputboxes=5&exercisename=Power+Clean&numsets=1&weightinputboxes=170&repinputboxes=3

Django Version: 1.3.1
Python Version: 2.7.0
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'authentication')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Chris\testdjango\fitness\views.py" in submitworkout
  34.     return render_to_response('home.html',{'infoprompt': workout(request.GET)},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
File "C:\Users\Chris\testdjango\fitness\tracking\models.py" in __init__
  15.             while numsetcounter < int(addworkout['numsets'][i]):   # u'numsets': [u'1', u'2']

Exception Type: IndexError at /submitworkout/
Exception Value: string index out of range
```

Comment: @JoelCornett: "Traceback or it didn't happen!". My feelings exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the way you are using the [QueryDict](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) object from `request.GET`. A QueryDict is initialized from the request's query string. The way a list of values are passed in a GET request is like `baz=1&baz=2`. When you directly access the value by a key as if it were a normal dict, you are only ever getting the last value that was added.

Use the QueryDict properly using [getlist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist):

```
exercises = addworkout.getlist('exercisename')
numsets = addworkout.getlist('numsets')
```

This will properly return lists of values.

Another option is to simply convert the QueryDict to a normal dict before passing it into your other method. This way it will have all the normal expanded values:

```
workout(dict(request.GET))
```

This is actually a really good idea because then your workout method won't have to have special knowledge of the QueryDict object. It can just treat it like a normal dict. It can then be used by any dictionary-like data structure besides a specific view-related situation.

Comment: numsets  = u'1' which means it should be valid shouldn't it

Comment: u'numsets': [u'1', u'1'], and which is validated through javascript. The length of exercisename and numsets will always be the same.

Comment: Hmm. Well if you have verified in your django view that they are both the same length, then I will have to keep looking at your examples. Have you tried doing a check at the top like:  `assert len(workout['exercisename']) == len(workout['numsets'])` ?

Comment: Uh no. Although they are the same length by just looking at the querydict which looks like this when i display it on my Django page instead of creating the workout object. addworkout =    
 {u'repinputboxes': [u'5', u'3'], u'weightinputboxes': [u'195', u'170'], u'numsets': [u'1', u'1'], u'exercisename': [u'Squat', u'Power Clean']}

Comment: And you were exactly correct with your second intuition. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

The error means that `addworkout['numsets']` is actually a string which length is smaller than `i`, as `addworkout['numsets'][i]` raises the exception. Given that your input dict has a list there, I assume that there is something wrong internally. Can you try debugging the contents of `addworkout` within the function call so you can make sure that it still contains the exact content you expect it to?